# Привязки трех вложенных списокв

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста как привязать 3 вложенных списка:

в ViewModel есть список проектов:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects{ get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Project>();

    private Project selProject;
    public Project SelProject {
        get { return selProject; }
        set
        {
            selProject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelProject");
        }
    }

    private Project selSec;
    public Project SelSec
    {
        get { return selSec; }
        set
        {
            selSec = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelSec");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {

        var pr1 = new Project("pr1");
        ObservableCollection<Section> sec = new ObservableCollection<Section> { new Section("sec1"), new Section("sec2") };
        ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model> { new Model("model1"), new Model("model2") };
        sec.First().Models.Add(models.First());
        sec.First().Models.Add(models.Last());
        sec.Last().Models.Add(models.First());
        sec.Last().Models.Add(models.Last());
        pr1.Sections.Add(sec.First());
        pr1.Sections.Add(sec.Last());
        Projects.Add(pr1);

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

класс Project:

```
 public class Project
{
    public string Projectname { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Section> Sections { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Section>();

    public Project(string name)
    {
        Projectname = name;
    }
}
```

в котором есть список разделов:

```
public class Section
{
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

    public Section (string name )
    {
        SectionName = name;
    }
}
```

в списке разделов есть список моделей:

```
public class Model
{
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public Model (string name)
    {
        ModelName = name;
    }
}
```

делаю привязку так:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelProject}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Projectname}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>


    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding SelProject}">
        <ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelSec}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=SectionName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding SelSec.Models}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=ModelName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

но последний ListBox не показывает список моделей, что я делаю не так?

Comment: у вас нет такого свойства `SelSec.Models`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
             Name="List1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelProject}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Projectname}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" 
             Name="List2" 
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=List1, Path=SelectedItem}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelSec}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=SectionName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="2"  
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=List2, Path=SelectedItem}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=ModelName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Плюс, можешь не писать в `OnPropertyChanged("SelSec")` наименование свойства, а можно просто `OnPropertyChanged()`, потому что в параметре метода написан атрибут CallerMemberName `[CallerMemberName]string prop = ""`, он автоматически подхватывает наименование свойства